# Unzip .app file without it turning into folders

Tags: macos, zip, compression

A company I work with have an issue where a zipped .app file is resolving into its bundled folders once unzipped.

What is the best way to compress an .app so that it can be decompressed without that it resolves into folders, that is the want it to remain a single .app file?

Use another format than zip? Compress it in binary?

Thanks in advance

Comment: An `.app` file is a bundle of folders...

Comment: If I understand correctly this sounds as though the compressed app folder is losing the attribute which marks it as a package. You should edit your question to show how the app is being compressed and uncompressed, the tools and versions used, the OS you're doing this on, etc. Someone will probably then be able to help you out without just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be having any problems with this.  As I'L'I points out, an application on the Mac *is* a bundle of folders.  It's just that the Finder presents it to the user as a single entity.

Zipping and unzipping the bundle won't change this.  The Finder recognises the `.app` extension and acts accordingly.  It is not necessary to set what used to be called the 'bundle' bit on the top-level folder.  That *would* get lost by round-tripping the app through a .zip file, but that's not important anymore.

So the real question is, how are you inspecting the unzipped copy of your app?  If it's via the command line, or some other tool that doesn't know (or care) that apps are really bundles then you will indeed get the behaviour you describe, even with the original.

I couldn't find any way to break the Finder's 'single entity' view of an app, even if I deliberately damaged it but maybe you have found a way.  If so, I'd be interested to know how you did it.